# Power BI SFDC Object Connection - Task - Navigation Query Error

Tags: salesforce, powerbi

I am hoping to get some help with the following error when I try to connect to the Task object in Salesforce. It is showing at the Navigation query (Task1 below) and I am unclear as to the nature of the error or resolution.

> DataSource.Error: exceeded 100000 distinct who/what's 
>   Details:
>       List

Query:

```
let
    Source = Salesforce.Data(),
    Task1 = Source{[Name="Task"]}[Data]
in
    Task1
```

The task volume in our SFDC instance is excessive, though I have previously been applying a date filter after the Navigation query (Task1 above) which is where I am currently experiencing the error, thus precluding me from using a date filter as I had been with other objects.

Thanks,

Rich

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission problem/limitation. You can find the solution [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-logs-errors#server-raised-fault-operation_too_large-exceeded-100000-distinct-who-what-s).